# Air Force courier with deadly biological agent caught in hostage drama

Tags: identify-this-movie

I saw this on TV in, I believe, the early 80s. It's about a group of people that are being held hostage by kidnappers and among them is an Air Force officer that is acting as a secret courier for a deadly biological agent. I can't remember most of the details, but the ending is that the lead kidnapper forces the Air Force officer to help him escape in a small plane. In the process, the hijacker finds the cigar case, and believing it to be a cigar, opens it to find the deadly agent. Rather than having this agent escape, the officer crashes the plane, sacrificing himself and his abductor. I've search all over IMDb for this to no avail.

Edit: A few additional details: there was a girl and her mother being held hostage and the girl ended up sleeping with one of the hijackers to save the rest of the hostages (this part is fuzzy and I think most of it was inferred). Also, I believe this movie may have come out in the 70s (but not 100% certain).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This sounds like it could be *The Night They Took Miss Beautiful* (1977), a TV movie.  Most of your description is echoed in this excerpt from an [IMDb user review](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0076458/reviews-5):

> Phil Silvers, in a rare departure from Bilko, plays the host of a beauty pageant. Him along with 5 beauty queens and one overbearing Mother all get kidnapped and put up for ransom by a group of terrorists. What the terrorists do not know is one of the pilots is carrying a deadly highly contagious biological nerve agent.
>
> It all gets rather dumb and the Mother urges her daughter to give herself to one of the terrorists to help them escape. In a thoroughly predictable ending all the terrorists and one of the pilots die and the beauty queen gets away from her overbearing mother.